# div em baixo de conteudo

Tags: html, css

Olá

eu tenho duas divs uma que é o carrossel e a outra que e o menu-secundario mas mesmo estando as duas em display block a div do carrossel fica por cima da div do manu-secundario, eu queria saber o porque e como resolver isto.

Codigo:

```css
.menu-secundario {
        background-color: rgba(45, 189, 129, 0.438);
        width: auto;
        height: 60px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header-1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .carrossel {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .menu-secundario li {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 81vw;
        padding-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .menu-principal {
        background: none;
    }
    .carrossel .b-V-A {
        display: none;
    }
    main {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .menu-burguer {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu-principal .menu-burguer img {
        width: 50px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
    .carrossel img {
        width: 100vw;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu-secundario">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Historias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Linha temporal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Impacto da poluição</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Percurso do rio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Jogo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            
            <div class="carrossel">
            <div class="img1 img" id="img1">
                <div class="seta-down">
                    <img src="../img/seta-down-conti-branco.png" alt="seta-down">
                </div>
                <div class="b-V-A">
                    <button class="b1"><a href="#img3">Voltar</a></button>
                    <button class="b2"><a href="#img2">Avançar</a></button>
                </div>
                <img src="../img/img_1_car.png" alt="img1">
            </div>
            <div class="img2 img" id="img2">
                <div class="b-V-A">
                    <button class="b1"><a href="#img1">Voltar</a></button>
                    <button class="b2"><a href="#img3">Avançar</a></button>
                </div>
                <img src="../img/img_2_car.jpg" alt="img2">
            </div>
            <div class="img3 img" id="img3">
                <div class="b-V-A">
                    <button class="b1"><a href="#img2">Voltar</a></button>
                    <button class="b2"><a href="#img1">Avançar</a></button>
                </div>
                <img src="../img/img_3_car.jpg" alt="img3">
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: É porque o menu está com um heigth fixo de 60px.

Comment: @Sam tentei mudar para auto e mudei a largura para 100vw mas continua igual... mudo a altura para o que para aquilo funcionar?

Comment: Não precisa declarar `auto`, esse valor já é o valor padrão da propriedade. E também não precisa colocar `100vw` na largura, pois a div já ocupa toda largura por padrão. Ao meu ver, basta apagar o `height` que já fica uma coisa abaixo da outra no layout.

Comment: @Sam provavelmente voce deve estar certo mas acabei de retirar a altura da div e mesmo assim continua por de baixo da outra div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala David, tudo bem? (:

O conteúdo do seu menu está sendo sobreposto porque você definiu uma altura para ele, que no caso foi um *height:60px*. Para solucionar seu problema então é simples, basta remover a propriedade *height* do seu CSS e pronto! Mas se for importante ter um tamanho pré-definido de fato, você pode usar a propriedade ***min-height***. Exemplo:

```
.menu-secundario {
    background-color: rgba(45, 189, 129, 0.438);
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;

    /**************************/

    min-height: 60px;
}
```

Dessa forma, você vai garantir que seu menu não será menor do que 60px, e ao mesmo tempo ele não vai quebrar seu layout caso os itens do menu sejam de tamanhos diferentes. :D

Espero ter ajudado, abração!